# Google Chrome breaks menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, menu

We currently have a dropdown menu that is broken in Chrome (and **ONLY** in Chrome).  It was working a week ago, and something has happened.

What happens is that when you click the dropdown menu and then click a flyout from the dropdown, the background of the flyout moves to the left side of the screen, and the background for the flyout becomes transparent.

It works correctly in every other browser (including ones based on Chromium) but not in Google Chrome.

The steps to replicate the issue are:

1. Go to https://solerastaging.wpengine.com.
2. Click the Solutions button on the menu.
3. Click the "Fleet Solutions" button on the dropdown.

The weird thing is that there are no JavaScript errors so that makes troubleshooting very hard.

We're wondering if Chrome had some update in the past few days that might have caused this and how we can fix it.

Comment: can you post the relevant HTML/CSS/JS for this issue - here's the thing with chrome ... it sucks ... every second release breaks some basic functionality for absolutely no reason ... wait for an update, and it suddenly works **as it should**

Comment: I would post the code but it's over 300000 lines of code.  And I didn't write it and the CSS is in SASS and I don't know that.

Comment: I didn't ask for **all** the code, just the relevant code - i.e. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's the problem.  I don't know what's relevant or not.  It was originally written in SCSS and I'm trying to learn it on-the-fly.

Comment: I'm with you... they used a build process and everything is minimized so it's like looking for a needle in a haystack of needles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution within this [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1338997), I think that issue is related to the issue you're seeing.  Add `display: table` to `.site-nav__primary>.menu-item-has-children>ul>.menu-item-has-children ul::before` until they get that bug sorted.  Apparently `display: table` will "trigger legacy engine fallback".

```
.site-nav__primary > .menu-item-has-children > ul > .menu-item-has-children ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 21.25rem;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-jacarta-20);
  background: var(--color-subtle);
  display: table /* <-- what you need */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help either.

Comment: @JohnSwaringen It does work.  Tested it again with and without.  Without I see the symptoms you described with the menu background to the left of the page.  With `display: table` it works like it should.  Try again, I have the code fully written out.  Make sure you put it in the `::before` pseudo element and be sure to clear your cache. Chrome Version 103.0.5060.114

Answer (score 1):

I tested this rule and it fixed the issue on your site in Chrome on a Mac.

```
ul.site-nav-multicolumn li {
    position: relative;
}
```

The background has a `position: absolute` so it will position itself absolutely based on the next previous parent up the tree that has a set position, ultimately ending at the body/html tag. The next element that had a position set was `header.site-nav` which was `position: sticky`. The left top most part of that element is top left of the screen, so that's why it was positioned at the top. Why it only worked everywhere but Chrome is another story. Cross-browser testing is it's own fun. Anyway, try that rule and let me know how you get on.

Comment: No problem! Things like that are mega annoying.

Comment: Looks like it didn't fix it afterall

Comment: What is it doing now? Same thing? Can you see that the style has applied or if browser cache is still applying the old css?

Comment: @Bjorn.B This solution makes it usable but my guess is that he wanted the submenu to start flush right under the header like in the original.  I found a hackish solution to the Chromium bug.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear to be a bug in Chromium.  Now it's happening in all Chromium-based browsers.

We're going to rewrite the menu.

Comment: as I said  ... *every second release breaks some basic functionality for absolutely no reason ... wait for an update, and it suddenly works as it should*